# SQL - Calculate row value based on previous row values for multiple entities at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, iterator

I have the following situation: I have a list of transactions belonging to many investments. A transaction record contains the investment identifier, date and gross amount but NOT the running balance.

**Transaction Table:**

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| Investment | Date       | Gross  |
+------------+------------+--------+
| A          | 2015-01-01 |   +200 |
| B          | 2015-06-30 |   +500 |
| C          | 2016-01-10 |   +300 |
| A          | 2016-08-15 |   +100 |
| A          | 2016-09-21 |   -300 |
+------------+------------+--------+
```

The balance is stored in a separate table, and is always current:

**Balance Table:**

```
+------------+------------+
| Investment | Balance    |
+------------+------------+
| A          |          0 |
| B          |        500 |
| C          |        300 |
+------------+------------+
```

What I would like to do is get the running balance for each transaction, for all investments up to a certain point at one time.

So for example, if I wanted to show transactions from Jan 1, 2016 to Aug 31, 2016 for investments A, B and C, with a running balance, I would get this:

**Result:**

```
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| Investment | Date       | Gross  | End Balance |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| C          | 2016-01-10 |    300 |         300 |
| A          | 2016-08-15 |    100 |         300 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

I would like to do this ideally without an iterator as I believe it is inefficient. Also, it would be ideal to use the Balance Table and work backwards from a current balance as an investment may have **many** transactions when I only typically need to display a few, and ones that are more recent.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: in Result how did you get the end balance for A?

Comment: @Kostya I did Current Balance minus Gross Value of all transactions after: So, 0 - (-300) = 300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CROSS APPLY to get the running balance

```
SELECT t.Investment, t.Date, t.Gross, b.Balance
FROM   Transaction t
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT balance = SUM(x.Gross)
           FROM   Transaction x
           WHERE  x.Invenstment = t.Investment
           AND    x.Date <= t.Date
       ) b
WHERE  t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
AND    t.Date <= '2016-08-31'
```

EDIT : to handle more than one trans with same date

```
; with Trans as
(
    SELECT *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Investment order by Date)
    FROM   Transaction
)
SELECT t.Investment, t.Date, t.Gross, b.Balance
FROM   Trans t
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT balance = SUM(x.Gross)
           FROM   Trans x
           WHERE  x.Invenstment = t.Investment
           AND    x.rn <= t.rn
       ) b
WHERE  t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
AND    t.Date <= '2016-08-31'
```

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel. This solution got me to:
 SELECT t.Investment, t.Date, t.Gross, b.balance
 FROM   Transaction t
     OUTER APPLY
     (
      SELECT balance = (Current_Balance - sum(t2.Gross))
      FROM   Balance x
    INNER JOIN Transaction t2 on t2.Investment = x.Investment
      WHERE  x.Investment = t.Investment
      AND t2.Date > t.Date
      GROUP BY x.Current_Balance
     ) b
 WHERE  t.Date >= '2016-01-01'
 AND    t.Date <= '2016-08-31'

But now I have an issue when there are two transactions on the same day. Any ideas to treat them separately? Thanks again

Comment: @KJY. Edited the query

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query if you are using SQL 2012 or higher version.

```
   ;with cte_1
    AS (SELECT    Investment,Date
                 ,Gross
                 ,SUM(Gross) OVER(Partition by Investment ORDER BY Date
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) EndBalance
                ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Investment Order By Date DESC)RNO
            FROM Transaction 
         WHERE Date between @starDate AND @endDate
         )

    SELECT     *
    FROM cte_1 A
    WHERE RNO =1
```